# The type initializer for 'NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration' threw an exception. Unit Testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, postgresql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have `UnitTesting` project with one `TestMethod` which calls repository and repository creates new record in `PostgreSQL`

When I run this test its throws exception:

Message: `The type initializer for 'NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration' threw an exception.`

Inner Exception: `{"The type initializer for 'NHibernate.LoggerProvider' threw an exception."}`

StackTrace:

```
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration..ctor()
   at FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration..ctor()
   at FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Fluently.Configure()
   at Woo.Test.UnitTest.FillCompany()
```

My repository works good when i call it from `ASP.NET MVC Applictaion`

This is my `Fluent NHibernate` configuration:

```
_configuration = Fluently.Configure().Database(PostgreSQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(c => c
               .FromConnectionStringWithKey("DefaultConnection"))).Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Company>())
               .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaUpdate(cfg).Execute(false, true)).BuildConfiguration();
_sessionFactory = _configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
```

So problem is only with unit testing project.

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configurations>
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=Test;User=postgres;Password=Test;" />
    </connectionStrings>
  </configurations>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unit test deployment works differently. You should mark any required file/assembly to be deployed within bin directory from *.testsettings file. See the screen below:

[image]

All you have to do now is to find the missing file/assembly and deploy it via testsettings file.

Answer (score 1):

You app.config has to be in the bin directory of the unit test. Check the properties of the app.config and see if it is deployed.

Comment: Thenks for replya. I have Copy always : Copy Always on app.config. It is not connection string problem. I have tried PostgreSQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString("Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=Test;User=postgres;Password=Test;") but it does works either.